# Change CultureInfo of string C#

Tags: c#, string, cultureinfo

I'm working on string with multiple cultures that convert form a numeric, and then I want to change it at runtime. Somthing like this:

```
ChangeCulture(inputText, CultureName)
```

and the output result will something like this: $1,000.52 or 1.565.155đ.
what should I do?

Comment: Strings don't have cultures, so you can't change it. You can, however, format a `decimal` using a culture to create a `string`. Does that help?

Comment: It sounds like you want to parse a string to a number using some culture, and convert it back to a string using some other culture. Both parsing and ToString methods usually have an overload that takes a culture. But the question lack details, if you want to include things like currency symbols that might need separate handling.

Comment: Best way is to use decimal.TryParseExact(culture1) and if you get a FALSE then try culture2.